# Enlarge search box using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How to extend the size of my search box with smooth animation using jQuery or CSS3 but not Java Script.

This my search box: http://jsfiddle.net/7CDRA/

I want when a user click in it, the size of the box to animate to 50, currently it is 20.

```
<form id="searchbox" method="get" action="http://www.google.com">
    <input type="text" name="q" size="20"><input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

Comment: `using jQuery [...] but not Java Script.` Hm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS(3)-only solution. No Javascript - so no jQuery ;)

```
#searchbox input,
#searchbox input:hover{
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#searchbox input:hover{
  width: 200px;
}

#searchbox input{
  width: 150px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7CDRA/10/

Comment: Edited so that the submit button doesn't change, and changed to on focus, rather than hover: 
http://jsfiddle.net/7CDRA/12/

Answer (score 3):

Using jquery animate would be the easiest:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: $(this).width()*2.5
    });
});

$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
    if(this.value == '') {
        $(this).animate({
            width: $(this).width()/2.5
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7CDRA/4/

This is a more bug-free example but with static width values:
http://jsfiddle.net/7CDRA/6/

Comment: @Martin: Where should I report bugs? If you click in/out a few times fast the box becomes rather large... borderline indecent one might say

Comment: Is there any change to make the same thing but not when click, just when a user hover it?

Comment: You can extend the functionality a lot, prevent animation stacking, etc. If you want a complete plugin you should probably google one. I gave you an idea on where to start.

Answer (score 0):

To use this, you need [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (javascript).

Here is a JsFiddle for what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/7CDRA/2/

```
<form id="searchbox" method="get" action="http://www.google.com">
            <input id="q" type="text" name="q" size="20"><input type="submit" value="search">
 </form>
```

Javascript :

```
 $("#q").click(function(){
   $(this).animate({width:"300px"},400); 
 });
```

Comment: OP said no javascript!

Comment: Okey, that's great but I also want when "Unclick" to go to normal size

Comment: Well, if this is easiest option I will be okey with it

Answer (score 0):

I like editing the height of the text box as well. [Here is a jFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7CDRA/11/).

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: $(this).width()*2.5,
        height: $(this).height()*1.5
    });
    var newFontSize = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
    newFontSize = newFontSize * 1.5;
    $(this).css({
        'font-size': newFontSize
    });
});

$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: $(this).width()/2.5,
        height: $(this).height()/1.5
    });
    var newFontSize = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
    newFontSize = newFontSize / 1.5;
    $(this).css({
        'font-size': newFontSize
    });
});
```